# Signals in ppoll not handled immediately

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I wrote a small ppoll test but I am confused about the signal handling. The man page says:

> The relationship between poll() and ppoll() is analogous to the relationship between select(2) and pselect(2): like pselect(2), ppoll() allows an application to safely wait until either a file descriptor becomes ready or until a signal is caught.

In my case fd changes are handled immediately while signals are handled after the timeout. I used ctr-c in the process context and kill from another shell but always the same behavior.

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss something?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <poll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handleSignal(int signal)
{
    switch(signal)
    {
        case SIGINT:
            std::cerr << "sigint" << std::endl;
            break;
        case SIGTERM:
            std::cerr << "sigterm" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "sig=" << signal << std::endl;
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int result;
    FILE *fd = fopen("/tmp/tmpFile", "r");
    result = fileno(fd);
    if(-1 == result)
    {
        std::cerr << "could not open temp file"  << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pollfd fds[2];
    fds[0] = { 0, POLLIN, 0 };
    fds[1] = {result, POLLIN, 0 };

    sigset_t mySigset, oldSigset;
    sigemptyset(&mySigset);
    sigaddset(&mySigset, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mySigset, SIGTERM);

    struct sigaction mySigHandler;
    mySigHandler.sa_handler = &handleSignal;
    mySigHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&mySigHandler.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &mySigHandler, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &mySigHandler, NULL);

    char buffer[1024];
    timespec time;
    while(true)
    {
        time = {20, 0};
        result = ppoll(&fds[0], 2, &time, &mySigset);
        if(0 == result)
        {
            // timeout
            std::cout << "ppoll timeout" << std::endl;
        }
        else if(0 > result)
        {
            // error
            std::cerr << "ppoll error" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // at least one fd changed
            std::cout << "active fds: " << result << std::endl;

            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                if(fds[i].revents & POLLIN)
                {
                    result = read(fds[i].fd, buffer, 1024);
                    if (-1 == result)
                    {
                        std::cerr << "error while reading fd " << fds[i].fd << std::endl;
                    }
                    else if(0 < result)
                    {
                        buffer[result] = '\0';
                        std::cout << "read fd " << fds[i].fd << ": " << buffer << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you called `ppoll`, you told it to block `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` by passing them in the signal mask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read the man page too much and was blind to solve this on my own. Make sense because otherwise I could just have used the poll function.